# Using Selenium to Find Element In an Array By Class Name

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to extract the text contained in a table with class name "infoBoxContents". However, there are multiple tables with this class name, and I am trying to extract text from the third table with this class name. I have tried the following code

```
String actual = browser.findElement(By.className("infoBoxContents")).getText();
```

which is naturally returning the text for the first table with  the above-mentioned class name. I have done a lot of research on how to reference the particular element of an array but I have not found anything.

How can I correctly access the text within the third table containing that class name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only looking for one element. This should fix the issue.

```
String actual = browser.findElements(By.className("infoBoxContents")).get(2).getText();
```